# Handles check of the current process does not return all open handles only the handle itself

Tags: c++, windows, permissions, system, handle

I'm making an anti cheat module that checks all open handles directed to the current process and the module should return all open handles whether they are from the system, from the user or whatever.
The problem is that it is returning only 1 handle and it is from the process itself.

Simultaneously with ProcessExplorer I am analyzing the current process and through ProcessExplorer I receive all the handles directed to it, example: ProcessExplorer, csrss, lsrss, svhost and etc.

Could someone help me to make the code return all the handles directed to the process like in ProcessExplorer?

I look forward to any contact.
Grateful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>


using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "psapi.lib")

#pragma region NT Structures

#define NT_SUCCESS(x) ((x) >= 0)
#define STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH 0xc0000004

#define SystemHandleInformation 16
#define ObjectBasicInformation 0
#define ObjectNameInformation 1
#define ObjectTypeInformation 2

#define PROCESS_QUERY (0x1400) 
#define PROCESS_FULL_CONTROL (0x1fffff) 

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* _NtQuerySystemInformation)(
    ULONG SystemInformationClass,
    PVOID SystemInformation,
    ULONG SystemInformationLength,
    PULONG ReturnLength
    );
typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* _NtDuplicateObject)(
    HANDLE SourceProcessHandle,
    HANDLE SourceHandle,
    HANDLE TargetProcessHandle,
    PHANDLE TargetHandle,
    ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
    ULONG Attributes,
    ULONG Options
    );
typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* _NtQueryObject)(
    HANDLE ObjectHandle,
    ULONG ObjectInformationClass,
    PVOID ObjectInformation,
    ULONG ObjectInformationLength,
    PULONG ReturnLength
    );

typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING
{
    USHORT Length;
    USHORT MaximumLength;
    PWSTR Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING, * PUNICODE_STRING;

typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE
{
    ULONG ProcessId;
    BYTE ObjectTypeNumber;
    BYTE Flags;
    USHORT Handle;
    PVOID Object;
    ACCESS_MASK GrantedAccess;
} SYSTEM_HANDLE, * PSYSTEM_HANDLE;

typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
{
    ULONG HandleCount;
    SYSTEM_HANDLE Handles[1];
} SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, * PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;

typedef enum _POOL_TYPE
{
    NonPagedPool,
    PagedPool,
    NonPagedPoolMustSucceed,
    DontUseThisType,
    NonPagedPoolCacheAligned,
    PagedPoolCacheAligned,
    NonPagedPoolCacheAlignedMustS
} POOL_TYPE, * PPOOL_TYPE;

typedef struct _OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION
{
    UNICODE_STRING Name;
    ULONG TotalNumberOfObjects;
    ULONG TotalNumberOfHandles;
    ULONG TotalPagedPoolUsage;
    ULONG TotalNonPagedPoolUsage;
    ULONG TotalNamePoolUsage;
    ULONG TotalHandleTableUsage;
    ULONG HighWaterNumberOfObjects;
    ULONG HighWaterNumberOfHandles;
    ULONG HighWaterPagedPoolUsage;
    ULONG HighWaterNonPagedPoolUsage;
    ULONG HighWaterNamePoolUsage;
    ULONG HighWaterHandleTableUsage;
    ULONG InvalidAttributes;
    GENERIC_MAPPING GenericMapping;
    ULONG ValidAccess;
    BOOLEAN SecurityRequired;
    BOOLEAN MaintainHandleCount;
    USHORT MaintainTypeList;
    POOL_TYPE PoolType;
    ULONG PagedPoolUsage;
    ULONG NonPagedPoolUsage;
} OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION, * POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION;

#pragma endregion

// for getting an address of a procedure in memory.
PVOID GetLibraryProcAddress(PSTR LibraryName, PSTR ProcName)
{
    return GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA(LibraryName), ProcName);
}

void EnableDebugPrivilege()
{
    HANDLE token;
    LUID luid;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;

    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &token);
    LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luid);
    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(tp), NULL, NULL);
    CloseHandle(token);
}

int Handle_Scan()
{
    EnableDebugPrivilege();

    while (1)
    {
        DWORD pid = GetCurrentProcessId();
        _NtQuerySystemInformation NtQuerySystemInformation =
            (_NtQuerySystemInformation)GetLibraryProcAddress("ntdll.dll", "NtQuerySystemInformation");
        _NtDuplicateObject NtDuplicateObject =
            (_NtDuplicateObject)GetLibraryProcAddress("ntdll.dll", "NtDuplicateObject");
        _NtQueryObject NtQueryObject =
            (_NtQueryObject)GetLibraryProcAddress("ntdll.dll", "NtQueryObject");

        NTSTATUS status;
        PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION handleInfo;
        ULONG handleInfoSize = 0x10000;
        HANDLE processHandle;
        ULONG i;

        processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY | PROCESS_FULL_CONTROL | PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE | PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS | PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);

        handleInfo = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)malloc(handleInfoSize);

        while ((status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation, handleInfo, handleInfoSize, NULL)) == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
            handleInfo = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)realloc(handleInfo, handleInfoSize *= 2);

        for (i = 0; i < handleInfo->HandleCount; i++)
        {
            SYSTEM_HANDLE handle = handleInfo->Handles[i];
            HANDLE dupHandle = NULL;
            POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION objectTypeInfo;
            PVOID objectNameInfo;
            UNICODE_STRING objectName;
            ULONG returnLength;

            if (handle.ProcessId != pid)
                continue;

            NT_SUCCESS(NtDuplicateObject(processHandle, (HANDLE)handle.Handle, GetCurrentProcess(), &dupHandle, 0, 0, 0));

            objectTypeInfo = (POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION)malloc(0x1000);
            NT_SUCCESS(NtQueryObject(dupHandle, ObjectTypeInformation, objectTypeInfo, 0x1000, NULL));


            if (handle.GrantedAccess == 0x0012019f)
            {
                std::free(objectTypeInfo);
                CloseHandle(dupHandle);
                continue;
            }

            objectNameInfo = malloc(0x1000);
            if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtQueryObject(dupHandle, ObjectNameInformation, objectNameInfo, 0x1000, &returnLength)))
            {
                objectNameInfo = realloc(objectNameInfo, returnLength);
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtQueryObject(
                    dupHandle,
                    ObjectNameInformation,
                    objectNameInfo,
                    returnLength,
                    NULL
                )))
                {
                    std::free(objectTypeInfo);
                    std::free(objectNameInfo);
                    CloseHandle(dupHandle);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            objectName = *(PUNICODE_STRING)objectNameInfo;
            wstring ObjectBuffer = objectTypeInfo->Name.Buffer;

            // We are only interested about handles to files & processes
            if (ObjectBuffer.find(L"File") != wstring::npos || ObjectBuffer.find(L"Process") != wstring::npos)
            {

                HANDLE CurrentProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
                HANDLE procHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY | PROCESS_FULL_CONTROL | PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE | PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS | PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, handle.ProcessId);

                HANDLE DuplicatedHandle = 0;

                // Duplicating the handle, now we can do basically anything with it.
                if (DuplicateHandle(procHandle, (HANDLE)handle.Handle, CurrentProcess, &DuplicatedHandle, 0, false, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
                {
                    WCHAR NameBlock[256];
                    wstring block = NameBlock;
                    K32GetProcessImageFileNameW(DuplicatedHandle, NameBlock, 256);

                    PathStripPathW(NameBlock);
                    wcout << L"Handle to " << ObjectBuffer << ": " << NameBlock << " Id: " << handle.ProcessId << endl;
                }
            }
            std::free(objectTypeInfo);
            std::free(objectNameInfo);
            CloseHandle(dupHandle);
        }

        std::free(handleInfo);
        CloseHandle(processHandle);
        cin.get();
    }
    return 0;
}


void DetectHandle() {
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(Handle_Scan), NULL, 0, 0);
}
```

I tried to add SetDebugPrivilege but it didn't help, I also tried to add more parameters in OpenProcess with the hope of a lack of permissions but I was unsuccessful again.